# Add new row to R data frame in for loop without using NROW()

Tags: r, dataframe

**Problem**

Add row to data frame in function for accuracy measurement.

**Effort in R**

The function compute_accuracy.func() returns the precision accuracy measurement. 
The IF loop invokes the compute_accuracy.func() and added new rows to the data.frame.

**Add New Row to Data Frame, Not Working**

Need to add new row to each for...loop with threshold used and precision computed. I'm new at this effort to add new rows to an R data.frame, dynamically inside the for...loop.

```
compute_accuracy.func <- function(t_threshold) {
  tryCatch({
    x <- accuracy.meas(full$y, loans_predict$fit, threshold=t_threshold)
    return(x$precision) 
  }, 
  error = function(e) return(e)
  )
}

df_accuracies <- data.frame(n=0, threshold=0, precision=0)
compute_for_values = seq(0.1,0.9,by=0.1)
for(i in compute_for_values){
  threshold = i
  precision <- compute_accuracy.func(i)
  df_accuracies[nrow(df_accuracies) + 1,] <- rbind(threshold, precision)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by this approach: resorted to vector approach rather than rbind, e.g., c() with variables inside c().

```
df_accuracies <- data.frame(n=0, threshold=0, precision=0)
compute_for_values = seq(0.15,0.95,by=0.1)
n=0
for(i in compute_for_values){
  n <- n+1
  threshold = i
  precision <- compute_accuracy.func(i)
  df_accuracies[nrow(df_accuracies) + 1,] <- c(n, threshold, precision)
}
```